# Not able to render a column using cell renderer when using group by

Tags: javascript, angular, ag-grid-angular

I have a ag grid which has multiple columns and one more column named **"More"**. The value of **More** depends on the value of other columns in that row. The value in column **More** is rendered using cell renderer using conditional statement which use value of other columns in the same row.

When I try to group by the grid using a certain column, in that case the column named **More** becomes blank for all rows.
Also I get error in the console that the inside the cellrenderer function the value of params is null, hence it could not read the data of params and the data of params contains the data of the row.